# Multiple errors in reading all files one by one

Tags: file, haskell, directory

I am trying to learn Haskell. I want to create a small program which gets list of files from current directory, read them one by one and prints their first line. I tried:

```
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)
import System.FilePath ((</>))

getAbsoluteDirContents :: String -> IO [FilePath]

getAbsoluteDirContents dir = do
  contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
  return $ map (dir </>) contents

readALine x = do 
  print $ "Filename: " ++ x
  f  <- hGetLine x
  print $ "First line: " ++ f 

main = do 
  files <- getAbsoluteDirContents "."
  print files
  map (readALine f) files
```

However, this code is giving following detailed error:

```
$ ghc -o firstline.hsx firstline.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( firstline.hs, firstline.o )

firstline.hs:13:9: error:
    • Variable not in scope: hGetLine :: [Char] -> IO [Char]
    • Perhaps you meant ‘getLine’ (imported from Prelude)

firstline.hs:19:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO b
        Actual type: [b]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: map (readALine f) files
      In the expression:
        do { files <- getAbsoluteDirContents ".";
             print files;
             map (readALine f) files }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { files <- getAbsoluteDirContents ".";
                   print files;
                   map (readALine f) files }

firstline.hs:19:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘FilePath -> b’
                  with actual type ‘IO ()’
    • Possible cause: ‘readALine’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(readALine f)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: map (readALine f) files
      In the expression:
        do { files <- getAbsoluteDirContents ".";
             print files;
             map (readALine f) files }
    • Relevant bindings include
        main :: IO b (bound at firstline.hs:16:1)

firstline.hs:19:18: error: Variable not in scope: f :: [Char]
```

I think main problem is `hGetLine` function is not correct. I saw this function [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:hGetLine).

There is also problem with `map (readALine f) files` expression.

Where are the problems and how can they be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to *import* the function in your file, like:

```
import Data.Text.IO(hGetLine)
```

But still there are a lot of errors here, sine `hGetLine` expects a `Handle` not a file path. You need to open the file first, with [**`openFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> IO Handle`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:openFile), and you need to close the handle after reading the line, with [**`hClose :: Handle -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hClose).

In your `main` you write:

```
map (readALine f) files
```

but `f` is not defined here. If you want to apply `readALine`, then you write `readALine`. Since `readALine` has type `String -> IO ()`, you should use [**`mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_).

Finally since [**`hGetLine :: Handler -> IO Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:hGetLine) returns an `IO Text` and not an `IO String`, you can not concatenate a `"first line: " :: String` to it, we can use the `OverloadedStrings` pragma, such that the `"first line: "` is interpreted as a `Text` here, and use the [**`(<>) :: Semigroup s => s -> s -> s**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--62-) to perform a concatenation.

Usually it is better to specify the signature of top level functions as well, although not strictly required, it shows some information about what the function is expecting as input and what it is doing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Semigroup((<>))
import Data.Text.IO(hGetLine)

import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import System.IO(IOMode(ReadMode), openFile, hClose)

getAbsoluteDirContents :: String -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsoluteDirContents dir = do
  contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
  return $ map (dir </>) contents

readALine :: FilePath -> IO ()
readALine x = do 
  print $ "Filename: " ++ x
  h <- openFile x ReadMode
  f  <- hGetLine h
  hClose h
  print $ "First line: " <> f

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  files <- getAbsoluteDirContents "."
  print files
  mapM_ readALine files
```

That being said, the program is still not working semantically correct, since your program will aim to open directories (like `.` and `..` as well). You thus will need to implement a proper filtering mechanism as well to prevent opening directories. You can use [**`isFile :: FilePath -> IO Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-fileio-0.3.16.4/docs/Filesystem.html#v:isFile) for this, I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I am trying `onlyFiles <- filterM doesFileExist files` but it is giving error `Variable not in scope: filterM ::....`

Comment: @mso: you need to import that as well, with `import Control.Monad(filterM)`

Comment: Pl see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207643/code-block-error-in-simple-if-then-statement